# Эффект появления всплывающего окошка на странице

Tags: jquery, эффекты

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется эффект появления всплывающего окошка на
[странице](http://demo.mosaicpro.biz/coral/php/admin/index.html?lang=en&skin=style-default) при наведении на "Adrian Demian" справа вверху?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе самому проще написать чем искать плагин, здесь обычный animate jquery
Вот накидал на скорую руку думаю дальше поймешь, через условие делай

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#js_hover").on('mouseover', function(){
            $("ul.dropdown-menu").css({"display": "block"});
            $("ul.dropdown-menu").animate({"padding-top": "0px"}, 200);
        });
        $(".dropdown-menu").on('mouseleave', function(){
            $("ul.dropdown-menu").css({"display": "none"});
            $("ul.dropdown-menu").css({"padding-top": "15px"});
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
    background: red;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.item {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item" id="js_hover">Menu</li>
    <li class="item">Menu1</li>
    <li class="item">Menu2</li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

tooltip menu fadeUp :)

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/TooltipMenu/

Comment: не совсем такой эффект, на примере он как-бы выезжает снизу чуть вверх, а на указанном вами просто fadeIn/Out

Comment: ну погуглите нужный и вас глючит, он не выезжает, там анимация сделана с помощью вот таких строк в css: 

    html.csstransitions.csstransforms3d .navbar.main .dropdown.open   .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-animation: fadeInUp 200ms linear;
    -moz-animation: fadeInUp 200ms linear;
    -ms-animation: fadeInUp 200ms linear;